# 3D Standing wave

Tags: waves, vibrations

I need to derive an equation (like a vibrating string) of a 3D vibrating object having a mass ‘m’(object itself made of bunch of closely packed particles, in-between the particles there should be an elastic joints something like a spring)  and shape of the object may be anything like torus ,hallow sphere, drum, 3D string , 3D circle, hallow ellipsoid. The thing is that there should be a standing wave with n harmonic.

Can I assume my problem like a single 3D harmonic oscillator or sum of k (a constant) number of   3D harmonic oscillators? If not how I can derive the equation?

Comment: 1, 2 , complexity. Complex system behavior begins with the number 3. You may be able to derive equations of motion, but not likely solve them without the help of a computer.

Comment: Have you looked at the Mathieu Equation? Maybe I'm too naive, but to me this sounds like such a problem, perhaps have a look at Am. J. Phys. 71, 233 (2003). There's a copy on the author's homepage if you don't have institutional access: http://homepages.mty.itesm.mx/jgutierr/Mathieu.html, paper 09.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you quite model an equivalent of an homogeneous elastic object. Then the answer is the eigenmodes of the Laplacian on this shape. It would be surprising to get a close form for most shapes; people usually solve this numerically.

I.e. it is the some of oscillators, but these are coupled at their shared borders, so configurations change the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is appropriate but still I need more clarification.